# File is being recreated even though it already exists

Tags: java, file

How does this code delete the file I had and makes a new one??

```
public void actualizaJTextArea(String cliente){
    mensagens.setText("");
    Scanner scanner = null;
    File file = createFile(cliente + "chatswith.txt");
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    (...)
    scanner.close();
}
public static File createFile(String s){
    File file = new File(s);
    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
            boolean b = file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
    return file;
}
```

Does the method `createNewFile()` do this? 
Thanks and I'm sorry if this has been asked before I just can't find it.

EDIT

I am also using `createFile()` in here to write in it but the use is the same so i guess that can't be it:

```
public void recebeMensagem(boolean b){
    while(true){
        Mensagem m = null;
        try {
            m = (Mensagem)input.readObject();
            System.out.println("Mensagem Recebida:"+m);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){ 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                input.close();
                System.out.println("Server desligou...");
                break;
            } catch (IOException e1) {

            }
        }
        if(m != null){
            for(Mensagens mensagens:v){
                for(String string: m.getReceivers()){
                    if (mensagens.getCliente().equals(m.getAuthor()) && mensagens.getContacto().equals(string)){
                        mensagens.actualizaJTextArea(cliente);
                    }   
                }
            }   
            for(String Str :m.getReceivers()){
                PrintWriter p = null;
                File file = Mensagens.createFile(cliente + "chatswith.txt");
                try {
                    p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    p.append(m.getAuthor()+"</<"+Str+"</<"+m.getText()+"\n");
                    p.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u sure u don't delete it elsewhere?

Comment: There is something else that you are not telling us,  the `createFile` will not create a file if it does exsist

Comment: sure sure, but i will look for delete() in the whole thing @nafas

Comment: @QuakeCore maybe it isn't deleting its just deleting the content somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createNewFile() is atomic and it will not delete the file if it is present. Please look at the boolean output, it should be false if your file exists already.

**EDIT**

add append parameter to FileWriter. It is overwriting every time.

FROM

p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));

TO

p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));

Comment: add append parameter to FileWriter. It is overwriting every time.